# XSLT transformation cannot work out how to include namespace?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to create an XSLT file, and I can get it to work without including the namespace in either file, but as soon as I do include in either, it stops working. 
here are the examples I'm using.

My XML file

```
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire sdf</title>
    <artist>Bob sdf</artist>
    <country>2</country>
    <company>asdfs</company>
    <price>12.90</price>
    <year>1935</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

My Transform file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html><body><table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32"><th>Title</th><th>Artist</th></tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>   
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table></body></html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Artist</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Empire Burlesque</td>
                <td>Bob Dylan</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Empire sdf</td>
                <td>Bob sdf</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

No if I alter the above to this.
My New XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog
xmlns="http://www.someurl.com/v3.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.someurl.com/v3.0 ../someschema.xsl"
>

  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire sdf</title>
    <artist>Bob sdf</artist>
    <country>2</country>
    <company>asdfs</company>
    <price>12.90</price>
    <year>1935</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

My New Transform file.

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.someurl.com/v3.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.someurl.com/v3.0 ../someschema.xsl">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
          <html><body><table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32"><th>Title</th><th>Artist</th></tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
            <tr>   
              <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
            </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </table></body></html>
        </xsl:template>

        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I now get no data out in my transformed file?
Please excuse if this question is basic, I have no experience with XSLT and I'm trying to wrap my head around it currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 : you just have to add in your `xsl:stylesheet` element the following attribute : `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.someurl.com/v3.0"`.

With XSLT 1.0 : you have to qualify your namespaces in the xsl file by giving a prefix. Example below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.someurl.com/v3.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.someurl.com/v3.0 ../someschema.xsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html><body><table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32"><th>Title</th><th>Artist</th></tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="ns:catalog/ns:cd">
                <tr>   
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="ns:title"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="ns:artist"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table></body></html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I added this to my xslt file but now get an unexpected attribute when running against it? and adding it to my xml file makes no difference?

Comment: Yes I correct it : xpath-default-namespace is only an xslt 2.0 feature. Sorry.

Comment: I can feel the penny nearing the edge :) thanks for your help.